# Displaying based on a string c#

Tags: c#

Okay so I am currently trying to make checkboxes based on if a string can be soon or not, however the data for each row in my grid will be different everytime so I can't set it to check one specific String, I was thinking along the lines of checking if that string was not nulled or empty but I don't know how to do this, I have an error in my code on the if (string.Equals line as I am unsure how to finish this off.

```
public class StringToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is string)
        {
            var input = (string)value;
            if (string.Equals
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Comment: I can't quite understand the question, but could you add a boolean to your ViewModel that determines the visibility?  Then have a BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET 4.0:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhitespace(myString))
```

.NET pre 4.0:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString))
```

Though, I would write the logic differently (some checks are not needed):

```
var input = value as string;
if (input == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
{
    return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
else
{
    return Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `IsNullOrEmpty` static method built into the `string` class, use that:

```
public class StringToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is string)
        {
            var input = (string)value;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would upvote and rep but not enough rep myself to do either of these things, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if a string is not null of empty then use:

```
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
       ////
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx):

```
if (string.IsnullOrEmpty(input))
{
    return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
else
{
    return Visibility.Visible;
}
```

If you additionally want to include white-spaces, use [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) (>= .NET 4.0).

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.IsNullOrEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx):

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string))
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
```